# How backbone observes the data change?

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, ember.js

Angular uses dirty checking to catch the data change and accordingly change the model or view. Ember sets observers to each elements to do this process.
But how does backbone do it?

Answer (score 1):

Backbone doesn't handle data changes for updating views (by default).

Let's see.

Backbone.Model has all the methods of Backbone.Events. So when the data changes, Model calls this.trigger() function.

But you should subscribe on "change" event to handle all data manipulations:

```
myModel.on('change:attributeName', myView.render, myView);
```

Maybe it would be better to say that Backbone uses setters and Backbone.Events to observe data changes.

Comment: so is it like, backbone doesn't have the auto binding feature? we have to code for it?

Comment: @PaulShan exactly. But feel free to use some plugins like [epoxyjs](http://epoxyjs.org/) for data bindings.

Comment: as for me, it is better to use `model.on('change', view.render)`. But everything depends on your own situation

Answer (score 1):

As @Leestex answered, backbone doesn't bind data changes for you.

but, it's better to use listenTo inside of the view. eg:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
  }

});
```

see:
http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo

Another way for the view to listen to model events is to attach a handler to the model, like this:

```
this.model.on('change', this.render);
```

But it's generally not recommended because you would have to detach the handlers manually using `off()`. When you're listening to multiple models, this can get messy and may lead to
[zombie views](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/).

The benefit of using `listenTo()` is that you can call `stopListening()`, which will unbind the callbacks associated with that object. In this case, that object is the view.